# Phonegap filetransfer, not working. imageuritoupload not defined?

Tags: javascript, php, android, cordova

I'm trying to upload a picture from my emulator, but I'm getting error **processMessage failed: imageUriToUpload is not defined** in the console. I followed the guide from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

So I'm pretty much blank here, don't know how to figure this out. uploadPhoto should get the imageURI from the capturePhoto method.

Capture photo method in the client:

```
function capturePhoto() {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(
                uploadPhoto, 
                function(message) { alert("Failed to get picture"); },
                {
                    quality: 50,
                    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
                }
            );
        }
```

Client code:

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
            var title1 = document.getElementById('title').value;
            var desc1 = document.getElementById('desc').value;

            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.key = "file";
            options.fileName= imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType= "image/jpeg";

            var params = new Object();
            params.title = title1;
            params.desc = desc1;

            options.params = params;
            options.chunkedMode = false;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://lols.com/php"), win, fail, options);
        }

        function win(result) {
            console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
            console.log("Response = " + r.response);
            console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
            alert(r.response);
            window.location.replace("http://hp1.vlab.cs.hioa.no/Hovedprosjekt/public/mobileupload")
        }

        function fail(error) {
            alert("fail");
            console.log(evt.target.error.code);
        }
```

Server code:

```
<?php 
print_r($_FILES["file"]);

$a = storage_path().'/mobileupload/'.'yolo.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $a);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a typo in `options.fileName= imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);` Fixed, and got past the error now.